# Pressure generated by a molecule inside an enclosure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, pressure

I want to find the pressure generated by a molecule of mass $m$  and speed $v$ that is alone in an enclosure having the volume $V$.

I wander if I can use the relation:

$PV=mv^2/2$

Comment: I do not understand the minus. The only one that could have awarded me with it is the user "ACuriousMind" because my question had only one view and one edit made by "ACuriousMind" when I saw the minus.

Comment: A single molecule in a volume $V$ doesn't exert pressure: it's as close to vacuum ($p=0$) as you can get. Pressure is a stochastic quantity: you need lots of molecules for that.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Don't worry about who downvoted your question; instead, you might consider what you could do to make this a better question.

Comment: Just as Daniel says, I would not worry about who downvoted your question, I would be more concerned about why? You may not have got a downvote if you had stated **why** you thought that was the correct relation to use.

Comment: @Gert Mostly true, although you actually only need lots of "collisions" with the walls to compute a pressure. So the question looks legit to me.

Comment: @Nicolas: for a container to experience pressure it must experience multiple collisions with gas molecules *at once*. A single molecule can't do that.

Comment: @Gert: You can define pressure even with instantaneous collisions ; then two collisions can't ever happen at the same time. However I agree that such a pressure would have some strange properties (would be anisotropic, for a start)

Comment: @Nicolas: you're playing with words. A single molecule banging about in an enclosure generates pressure no more than one hand clapping generates sound. The OP doesn't understand what generates pressure, hence the dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Ideal Gas Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law#Statistical_mechanics)

You can use relation PV=Nk_{B}T where k_{B} is Boltzmann constant=1.38*10^-23 J/K For volume of 1m^3 and T=300K you will get P=k_{B}*300=4*10^-21 Pa. For comparison, [ultra high vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-high_vacuum) is defined as pressure lower than 10^-7 Pa.

Answer (score 0):

In all the gas laws, it was assumed that the vector sum of momentum of all those molecules is zero.That is a pretty strong assumption in that case. But here obviously, its not zero. Due to this reason, the force on  'The walls of a container' per unit area, depends on the 'wall' you are choosing, which also depends on the alignment of initial velocity vector with respect to the walls. For example, if you assume your initial velocity to be parallel to an arbitrarily chosen x axis, and if you take your volume 'V' to be a cube with its sides parallel to the axes. Then the mass would keep bouncing on the walls having their normal vectors pointed in x and -x direction only. And you would calculate a finite pressure on those walls and zero in any other. My point is, you cannot define 'gas pressure' with one single molecule. Need to hav such a number neccessary to nearly satisfy the assumption that force on all those walls are the same, at any point of time.After all , pressure is defined as force on 'the walls' and not on 'a  wall' of a randomly chosen container(irrespective of its shape)